# Assimp update to 5.0.1 issue with bone mname and mnumweights

Tags: c++, animation, assimp

Assimp was working fine previously, but with the update to 5.0.1 it seems bone mName and mNumWeights are messed up. What am I doing wrong here? I changed nothing regarding the model or the following printf statements.

[image: printf for *aimesh]

Comment: I downloaded assimp 4.1.0, recompiled / linked, and now it's working. I probably just built and linked 5.0.1 wrong. I'll leave the question open in case someone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it was an error on my end. Just set up another project with 5.0.1 and it works fine. I think I forgot to copy over the config.h after building assimp. Okay, I'll follow the link if I run into any issues

Comment: The config.h file will be generated by our build system based on cmake. So when starting your cmake run the config file shall be generated there as well.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not known right now. It would be great if you could provide a small reproducible example on our issue-page. It can be found here [Assimp-bugtracker](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues) Please use the Bug-workflow.